# How do I change Linux guest static IP when using VMware Site Recovery Manager

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vmware-srm

I have a Linux guest in VMware that been assigned a static IP, not using DHCP.

Whats the best way to change its IP when SRM is used to move the VM to another site ?

My Knowledge of VMware is limited and google brings up two methods which seem to be either use a script that SRM calls or have IP addresses defined in SRM for live and failover domains - but not sure if I can do this if the Linux VM is not using DHCP ?

Can anyone point me down the right path?

The VM guest is Ubuntu 16.